# iOS - How can I get links with different colors in UITextView?

Tags: hyperlink, uitextview, nsattributedstring, uicolor

I need to append some text lines to my UITextView.
Each text line is a link displaying a date (e.g. December 14th 2016).
The Detect Event checkbox on IB is not marked.

If the date has been already added to the calendar, I would like to display this line as a red link, so when the user taps on it, I remove the event from the calendar.

If the date hasn't been yet added to the calendar, I would like to display this line as a green link, so when the user taps on it, I add the event to the calendar. So I need to create links with 2 colors.

As I have checked, I can just use one only color for the links.
I tried to add custom attributes to the line

```
NSDictionary *linkAttributes = @{NSForegroundColorAttributeName:[UIColor greenColor], NSFontAttributeName:font, NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName : @(NSUnderlineStyleSingle) };
        [dateLine addAttributes:linkAttributes range:range];
```

But this line results as non-clickable. And if I add the link attribute

```
[dateLine addAttribute:NSLinkAttributeName value:URL range:range];
```

I get always the same and one only tint color on every link. Any clue?